# Why is nothing happening when I click on onclick button?

Tags: javascript

*I want to display two input fields for lower and higher number and display the necessary error messages if the inputs are wrong.

Any idea why nothing happens when I click on my button? Any way I can shorten my if-else statement cus it does feel quite wordy thank you would appreciate the comments*

```
<html> Enter lowest number<br>
        <input type="text" id="input"  size="20">
        <span id="wrongInput"><br><br>
        
        Enter highest number<br>
        <input type="text" id="input2" size="20">
        <span id="wrongInput2"></span><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="testNum()">Play button</button><br><br>
 </html>
        
<script>
function testNum()
{
//if is not a number or blank input
    if (/^\d$/.test(input) == '') 
    {
        var blank = document.getElementById("wrongInput").innerHTML;
        blank.innerHTML = "Please fill in a number"; 
        blank.style.color ="red"; 
        return false; 
    } else {
        blank.innerHTML = "";
    }
    
    if (/^\d$/.test(input)  == false)
    {   
        var wrong = document.getElementById("wrongInput").innerHTML;
        wrong.innerHTML = "Only key in number";
        wrong.style.color ="red";
        return false; 
    } else {
        wrong.innerHTML = ""; 
    }
    
    if (/^\d$/.test(input2) == '')
    {   
        var blank = document.getElementById("wrongInput2").innerHTML;
        blank.innerHTML = "Please fill in a number"; 
        blank.style.color ="red"; 
        return false;
    } else {
        blank.innerHTML = "";
    }
    
    if (/^\d$/.test(input2)  == false)
    {   
        var wrong = document.getElementById("wrongInput2").innerHTML;
        wrong.innerHTML = "Only key in number";
        wrong.style.color ="red";
        return false; 
    } else {
        wrong.innerHTML = ""; 
    }
    
    if (input2 < input)
    {
        var wrong = document.getElementById("wronginput2").innerHTML;
        wrong.innerHTML = "The number must be higher"; 
        wrong.style.color ="red";
        return false; 
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: why is your `script` tag outside the `html` altogether

Comment: `var blank = document.getElementById("wrongInput").innerHTML; blank.innerHTML = ...` This is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function is called in your example, there are just a few things listed below, that I think you should consider.

First of all you are trying to call an undefined variable in all of the else-blocks.

Second, you are calling innerHTML twice in all of the if statements.

Finally you need to take a look on your conditions in the if statements.